# Are parameters stored as local variables?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, memory-management, flash-cs6

Pretty simple question here: are parameters treated as local variables, in terms of memory allocation?

For example take these two functions:

```
function foo(parameter:Number):void
    {
        trace("Parameter =", parameter);
    }

    function bar():void
    {
        var x:Number;
        trace("x is a number", x is Number);
    }
```

Does ActionScript handle both `parameter` and `x` in the same way? Are they both created as local variables each time the function is run, and will remain in existence until GC gets rid of them, or are parameters treated differently?

Comment: Parameters are usually handled as references, unless they're primitive data types like int, number and so on. Which means that no, they are not treated like new local variables. [Source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html)

Comment: @NotAPro They are handled a little differently, but for all intents and purposes a parameter is a local variable. Why do you ask?

Comment: A parameter is local because it cannot be used anywhere outside of that function. So yes, it has to be local to that function and yes, it is garbage collected the same way as any locally defined variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does ActionScript handle both `parameter` and `x` in the same way? Are
>   they both created as local variables each time the function is run,
>   and will remain in existence until GC gets rid of them, or are
>   parameters treated differently?

The runtime handles parameters a little differently than local variables, but in the end they are both local scope and cleaned up when the function returns. For all intents and purposes a parameter is a local variable.

What's important to understand is [how arguments passed to functions work in AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html).

> In ActionScript 3.0, all arguments are passed by reference, because
>   all values are stored as objects. However, objects that belong to the
>   primitive data types, which includes `Boolean`, `Number`, `int`, `uint`, and
>   `String`, have special operators that make them behave as if they were
>   passed by value.
>
> All other objects—that is, objects that do not belong to the primitive
>   data types—are always passed by reference, which gives you ability to
>   change the value of the original variable.

In other words:

```
function test(primitive:int, complex:Array):void {
    primitive = 1;
    complex.push("foo");
}

var i:int = 0;
var a:Array = [];
test(i, a);
trace(i); // 0
trace(a); // ["hi"]
```